# Every second tag on my tumblr theme disappears

Tags: tags, tumblr

The html tag block is normal, so I can only imagine it must be coming from a div somewhere but I cannot think of what would cause only every second tag to disappear and leave the others in tact.

```
   .entry{
            margin:25px;
            margin-bottom:30px;    
            padding:5px 5px 2px 5px;
            height:auto;
            {block:IndexPage}overflow:hidden;width:250px;float:left;{/block:IndexPage}
            {block:PermalinkPage}width:500px;height:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;{/block:PermalinkPage}}



<div id="content">
{block:Posts}
<div class = "autopagerize_page_element" >
<div class="entry">



{block:PermalinkPage}
<div style="display:block;margin-top:10px;">
{block:Caption}<div style="margin-top:10px;">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
{block:HasTags}{block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}>#{Tag}&nbsp;</a>{/block:Tags}{/block:hasTags}


<br>{block:NoteCount}{NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}


{/block:PermalinkPage}

{block:PostNotes}
<div style="width:500px;height:250px;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;margin-left:-5px;margin-top:10px;">{PostNotes}</div>
{/block:PostNotes}
</div>
</div>
{/block:Posts}
```

Comment: You need to post some code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. To add to @lharby comment code and an link / example of the issue will help you get more responses.

Comment: @lharby ah yes, sorry meant to do that. as the tag block is normal, i'll just post the whole thing.

Comment: Can you add a link to the tumblr account too?